# AD Powershell: Bulk remove users from group via UserPrincipalName

Tags: powershell

I have a CSV file with users in userprincipalname and i need to remove them from a specific security group. I tried a number of different methods i found online, but all of them need samaccountname. This is the best i could come up with, it does work but it is extra output input that i don't think i need. Can anyone clean this up for me?

```
$CSV = 'C:\Temp\users.csv'
$CSVSAM = 'C:\Temp\userssam.csv'
$GROUP = 'SecurityGroup'

Import-CSV -Path $CSV | 
ForEach-Object {
    $upn = $_.UserPrincipalName
    Get-ADUser -Filter "UserPrincipalName -eq '$upn'" -Properties SAMAccountName | 
        Select-Object -Property SAMAccountName | Export-Csv -Path $CSVSAM -NoTypeInformation
    }

Import-Csv -Path $CSVSAM |
ForEach-Object {
    Remove-ADGroupMember -Identity $GROUP -Members $_.'SAMAccountName' -Confirm:$false
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the [documentation for `Remove-ADGroupMember`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/activedirectory/remove-adgroupmember?view=windowsserver2022-ps), I was at first surprised to see UPN was not one of the items for the `-Members` argument. But then I also saw this:

> You can also provide objects to this parameter directly.

So we should be able to do this:

```
$CSV = 'C:\Temp\users.csv'
$GROUP = 'SecurityGroup'

Import-CSV -Path $CSV | 
ForEach-Object {
    $upn = $_.UserPrincipalName
    $user = Get-ADUser -Filter "UserPrincipalName -eq '$upn'" 
    Remove-ADGroupMember -Identity $GROUP -Members $user  -Confirm:$false 
}
```

The argument also accepts an array, so we may further be able to do this, which, if it works, *might* be faster:

```
$CSV = 'C:\Temp\users.csv'
$GROUP = 'SecurityGroup'

$users = Import-CSV -Path $CSV | 
    ForEach-Object {
        $upn = $_.UserPrincipalName
        # Result of below command is placed on the pipeline
        Get-ADUser -Filter "UserPrincipalName -eq '$upn'" 
    } 
Remove-ADGroupMember -Identity $GROUP -Members $users  -Confirm:$false
```

Comment: This worked perfect. Thank you. I clicked the up arrow, but it warned that I am too new to have my feedback displayed.

Comment: Quick update, I tried your second suggestion and it is MUCH quicker. Thank you!

Comment: @KHdoesntCODE  In my organization, I am also able to infer the SamAccountName based on the UPN, which might also speed up the script by letting you use the `-Identity` argument for `Get-ADUser` instead of `-Filter`. (We have exactly 4 users with legacy accounts where the SamAccountName is not found by just stripping the domain from the UPN, and 2 of those could retire in the next year).